# Create Vector From Image

Tags: wpf, xaml, vector, bitmap

I've read 1,000 posts saying it's possible, but for the life of me, I can't find how to create a vector in XAML from a PNG. Could somebody please point me to any posts that explain how I can create a vector from a PNG for use in a WPF application?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Hopefully this will help

Download and install [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) (internally using [Potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/)). Here is a good article on the subject:
[Vectorize Bitmaps to XAML using Potrace and Inkscape](http://blog.tiaan.com/link/2009/02/21/vectorize-bitmaps-to-xaml-using-potrace-inkscape).
Here is a summary from the link..

- Run Inkscape
- Select **"File -> Open"** and browse to PNG
- When asked about **"Link or embed image:"**, select "embed"
- Select the newly opened image with the Mouse
- Select **"Path -> Trace Bitmap..."**
- Select **"Colors"** in the **"Multiple scans: create a group of paths"** GroupBox
- Select **"OK"** to execute the trace
- Close the "Trace Bitmap" Window
- Delete the original image by selecting **"Edit -> Invert Selection"** and press Delete.
- Choose **"File -> Save As..."**, select **"Microsoft XAML"** and save

..and you should have your XAML file converted from a PNG.

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot! However, the traced images (especially if they have 3D objects) looks blurry and different from the original image. Is there a way to improve their quality?